# What figure(s) of speech or expression are in play here?

Tags: poetry, figures-of-speech, rhetorical-devices

I recently heard a somewhat poetic song lyric that I couldn't pin down. The writer says of a failed relationship:

> We broke a diamond with our bitter words.

I get *diamond* as a metonym for marriage, or at least for commitment, but the writer stretches it by ‘breaking’ a diamond, which seems more metaphoric. It's nicely compact and expressive, but what's going on underneath?

Or maybe I'm missing something obvious. How would you characterize this lyric?

Answer (score 2):

This, unfortunately, is an example of a mixed metaphor.

The first part speaks of a diamond metaphorically, then goes on to say that the implement that destroyed it was "bitter"—a term involving the sensation of taste. Now, one could go on exuding flavors for a very long time before sundering a diamond. More precise might be "sharp" or "incisive" or "hard-edged" (to keep the same meter as the two-syllable "bitter"), and any of these would support the initial metaphor. Instead, "bitter" forces it off in another direction.

Comment: Surely poetic license permits some rule-breaking in service of being evocative? This isn't formal exposition, after all. 'Off in another direction' is often the essence of poetry.

Answer (score -1):

I would say this is ****hyperbole**--1.obvious and intentional exaggeration or 2.extravagant statement or figure of speech not intended to be taken literally, as "to wait an eternity". The diamond is probably the hardest substance on Earth. The bitter words between the two were so cutting, the words were able to break (cut through) diamonds.